# Detecting new or returning customer in spreadsheet formula

Tags: excel, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I am trying to test a dataset in a spreadsheet to see if a purchase was made by a first time customer or a returning customer. My columns are date, amount, and email, and I need a formula to test whether a customer is making a purchase for the first time. I am having trouble figuring out how to test the email against the rest of the dataset to see if it is the first time it has occurred. Please let me know if you need additional information, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You want "*to test the email against the rest of the dataset to see if it is the first time it has occurred*".

There are many functions that can accomplish this.
If the email you want to test is in cell F1, and the range of emails (*the rest of the dataset*) is in cells C2:C100, then use, e.g.,

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(F1,$C$2:$C$100,0)),"Not found","OK")
```